# What is the difference between these two async ternary statements?

Tags: javascript, async-await, conditional-statements, ternary

Can someone help me understand the difference if any between these two below ternary statements?

```
const variables = await (conditional ? asyncFunctionOne() : asyncFunctionTwo());
    
const variables = conditional ? await asyncFunctionOne() : await asyncFunctionTwo();
```

At first glance, these both do the same thing, but some part of me thinks these do not execute in the same order.

Comment: Same thing. What exactly was your doubt about execution order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be a small difference if this were a function call:

```
const variables = doSomething(conditional ? functionOne() : functionTwo());
    
const variables = conditional ? doSomething(functionOne()) : doSomething(asyncFunctionTwo());

const temp = conditional ? functionOne() : asyncFunctionTwo();
const variables = doSomething(temp);
```

These may look equivalent on a first glance, but are not if the code in `conditional` or even inside `functionOne`/`functionTwo` does change the `doSomething` variable.

However, `await` is not a function but syntax, its meaning is determined when parsing and compiling the code, not when evaluating it and resolving a variable. So the two lines in your question are absolutely equivalent.